# What will be best breakfast post 10K runs?

Tags: running, diet

Currently am running 6K but planning to go for 10K. I am doing it on concrete surface 5 times per week and there are no options available for me regarding surface.I am gonna take care of my body regarding good shoe, good posture,pre post stretching and others when it comes to running on concrete. Now to increase my longevity i am wondering what will be best breakfast for me so that my joints fluids and my joints are working in top condition. I am new to running world.

Currently i am having :
- 1 glass lime juice (straight outta lime).
- 2 half-fry eggs
- 500ml milk

Comment: There's no such thing as a "best" breakfast for anything, since each person's body will work differently depending on the situation. However, having protein + carbs after any kind of workout is recommended. What you're having seems pretty decent (although I think you could use some carbs; people usually enjoy toast with their eggs), but way more important that your breakfast will be your whole diet throughout the week, since running a 6K five times a week is pretty taxing.

Comment: and i am gonna up it to 10K (5 times per Week). My apprehension is i am running on concrete (and i don't have other options ) so want my bones and joints to be in terrific condition to take the beating of concrete.

Comment: Your breakfast seems fine. You might try some maltodextrin to your milk if you feel the need to increase carbohydrates.

I'd suggest increasing the distance in increments (first to 7K, then to 8K and so on) to help your body (especially your feet) to adapt to the increased workload. Going from 30km => 50km / week seems pretty taxing.

Also, what are your goals in running? I would suggest changing your running routine somewhat depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: It is currently 10K. I am not considering time for now, i am able to do 7.2K in 40mins round about so. Goals are first reach 10K then work on timings. I am increasing intervals by .6 K per week. Till now body seems fine. Just little pain on shin bone but that i suppose will be there in initial stage.

Comment: I'm curious how you get a glass of lime juice out of a lemon? :p

Comment: cause I am Chuck Norris :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of post-running nutrition, there are a lot of thoughts surrounding this - but there is one major theme, ensuring that you have carbohydrates to replace the energy you have used (refuelling), and protein for muscle repair (I can see that you already have eggs, and milk, which is good!). In terms of recovery, it is often touted that a 4:1 (or sometimes 3:1) carb:protein ratio is optimal, and that the protein should be consumed within an hour of finishing the run (as this is the time that it will have the most effect) - however, the body can only make use of so much protein per hour (based on your body weight), and different sources of protein act over different timescales (milk protein, for example, acts over a longer timescale than whey protein). Resources on websites such as RunnersWorld cover these topics.

So, having established the composition of what you should be eating - it's a case of working out a good way of having a wholesome breakfast that incorporates this!

As you run before breakfast, which naturally means your body is depleted, you must definitely ensure that you have carbs (porridge, etc) otherwise you may feel sluggish towards lunchtime as you increase your distance.

Here is a nutrition section from RunnersWorld,
http://www.runnersworld.com/tag/nutrition-for-runners

Here is an article for joint-health
http://www.runnersworld.com/nutrition-for-runners/joint-food

Here is an article outlining the timings for protein intake
http://www.runnersworld.com/nutrition-for-runners/protein-timing-for-runners

As you are just starting out running, these sorts of articles will help you on your way - I hope this helps, and all the best!